# How do I get AzureAppConfiguration working on a .NET Framework 4.7.2 MVC Application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a need to use AzureAppConfiguration to control feature flags on a .net framework 4.7.2 MVC application. I followed the tutorial from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-dotnet), but this tutorial only shows this configuration on a console application and there is surprisingly few discussions around the web about this (probably because it's much more simple than I am making it out to be).

My best translation of this was to put the configuration in Application_Start of the global.asax, but for some reason the configuration is not refreshing.

4765 variations later, I put the code into the Application_BeginRequest portion of the lifetime. This triggers a call to the config service on every request (as expected).

I am not exactly sure what I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My test project is on [github here](https://github.com/ehaltom/FeatureFlagsInMvcFramework) but you'll need to set up an azure configuration app with some features.

Here is an example of my latest attempt...

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static IConfiguration _configuration = null;
    private static IConfigurationRefresher _refresher = null;

    public void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                options.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfigConnectionString"))
                    .UseFeatureFlags().ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
                    {
                        refresh.Register("FeatureManagement")
                            .SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    });

                _refresher = options.GetRefresher();
            }).Build();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        FeatureUtilities.PopulateFlags(_configuration.GetSection("FeatureManagement").GetChildren());
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use the FeatureManagement.AspNetCore library, but that doesn't seem to pick up on the configuration at all. If this is not going to be possible, I can roll my own attributes and utilities.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm currently struggling with the exact same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above was the best we could get. I didn't put much effort into this after my post, and I've also noticed some buginess to it as well from time to time. Every once in a while we get connection errors (although that could be due to Azure's stellar reliability as of late). I will say the performance is pretty darn good with this though, which is why I didn't revisit this yet.